# Minesweeper: Mouse listener problem

Tags: java, graphics, mouse, minesweeper

I have wrote a code for game **Minesweeper** and there is no problem with the graphics,but there is some problems with **MouseListener**. Here is my code

---

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mines_v3.pkg0;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author Gevorg Hindoyan 
 * @version 3.0
 * @since 2012
 */
public class Mines_v30 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MineFrame frame = new MineFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MineFrame extends JFrame {
    private int xq = 10;
    private int yq = 10;
    private int minq = 10;
    public MineFrame() {

        setSize((xq+1)*22-1, (yq+2)*22+44);
        setTitle("Mines v.3.0");

        Image ic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/icon.png");

        setIconImage(ic);

        mainFields mf = new mainFields(xq,yq,minq);

        add(mf);
    }
}

class mainFields extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    private int xq;
    private int yq;
    private int minq;
    private boolean loose;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean win() {
        int smq = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=xq;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=yq;j++) {
                if(a[i][j]==-5 && b[i][j]==2) smq++;
            }
        }
        if(smq==minq) return true;
        return false;
    }
    private int a[][] = new int[100][100];
    private int b[][] = new int[100][100];
    private void init() {

        loose=false;
        // making all fields "0"
        for(int i=1;i<=xq;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=yq;j++) {
                a[i][j]=0;
                b[i][j]=0;
            }
        }

        //filing borders with -3
        for(int i=0;i<=xq+1;i++) {
            a[0][i]=-3;
            a[yq+1][i]=-3;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=yq+1;i++) {
            a[i][0]=-3;
            a[i][yq+1]=-3;
        }

        //adding mines
        Random rand = new Random();
        int nx=0,ny=0;
        for(int i=0;i<minq;i++) {
            int 
            x = rand.nextInt()%xq+1,
            y = rand.nextInt()%yq+1;
            if(x==0 || y==0) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            if(x<0) x*=-1;
            if(y<0) y*=-1;

            if(i==0) {
                nx = x;
                ny = y;
            } else if(nx==x && ny==y) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }

            a[x][y]=-5;

        }

        //filling with numbers
        for(int i=1;i<=xq;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=yq;j++) {
                if(a[i][j]==-5) {
                    if(a[i-1][j]>=0) a[i-1][j]++;
                    if(a[i+1][j]>=0) a[i+1][j]++;
                    if(a[i][j+1]>=0) a[i][j+1]++;
                    if(a[i][j-1]>=0) a[i][j-1]++;
                    if(a[i+1][j+1]>=0) a[i+1][j+1]++;
                    if(a[i+1][j-1]>=0) a[i+1][j-1]++;
                    if(a[i-1][j+1]>=0) a[i-1][j+1]++;
                    if(a[i-1][j-1]>=0) a[i-1][j-1]++;
                }
            }
        }

        /*DEBUG: printing matrix*/
        for(int i=0;i<=xq+1;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=yq+1;j++) {
                if(a[i][j]<0)
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
                else
                    System.out.print(" "+a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        /* DEBUG */
    }
    public mainFields(int xq1,int yq1,int mq1) {

        xq=xq1;
        yq=yq1;
        minq=mq1;
        width = (xq+1)*22-1;
        height = (yq+2)*22+44;
        init();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //status bar & all fields
        Image smile = null;
        String smile_name = "images/smile";
        if(loose) smile_name+="2";
        else if(win()) smile_name+="3";
        else smile_name+="1";
        smile_name+=".png";
        try {
            smile = ImageIO.read(new File(smile_name));
        } catch(IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        g.drawImage(smile, width/2-21,
                    0,
                    smile.getWidth(null), 
                    smile.getHeight(null), 
                    null);
        for(int i=1;i<=xq;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=yq;j++) {
                Image field = null;
                String fname = null;
                if(b[i][j]==0) {
                    fname = "datark";
                }
                else if(b[i][j]==2 && !loose) {
                    fname = "drosh";
                }
                else if(b[i][j]==2 && loose && a[i][j]!=-5) {
                    fname = "sxal_drosh";
                }
                else if(b[i][j]==1) {
                    if(a[i][j]==0) {
                        fname = "sxmats";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==1) {
                        fname = "mek";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==2) {
                        fname = "erku";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==3) {
                        fname = "ereq";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==4) {
                        fname = "chors";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==5) {
                        fname = "hing";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==6) {
                        fname = "vec";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==7) {
                        fname = "yot";
                    }
                    if(a[i][j]==8) {
                        fname = "ut";
                    }
                }
                fname+=".png";
                try {
                    field = ImageIO.read(new File("images/"+fname));
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error 1: can't find images");
                }
                g.drawImage(field,
                            (i-1)*22,
                            (j-1)*22+42,
                            null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    private void click(int i, int j) {

        b[i][j]=1;
        System.out.println("click() was called");
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        int x = me.getX(),
            y = me.getY();

        int xrd = (int)x/22+1,
            yrd = (int)(y-42)/22+1;

        int but = me.getButton();

        System.out.println("Mouse clicked");

        if(but == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {

            if(b[xrd][yrd]==1 || b[xrd][yrd]==2) {
                return;
            }
            click(xrd,yrd);
            repaint();
            this.repaint();

        }

        if(but == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {

            if(b[xrd][yrd]==2) {
                b[xrd][yrd]=0;
            } else if(b[xrd][yrd]==0) {
                b[xrd][yrd]=2;
            }
            repaint(); 

        }
    }

}
```

---

## EDIT

My function `click()` is not finished
And matrix `b[][]` is showing is that field is clicked
matrix `a[][]` is showing is that filed mine(-5) or number(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

The issue, as mentioned in chat, is that a click handler wasn't getting fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to hook up your listener.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to put addMouseListener(this); to your frame/panel